# LXC : Is it from linuxcontainers.org or part of Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

I want to know about LXC and came across this site: `https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/introduction/`; in this site, it talks about `LXC`, `LXD`, among others.

I am a bit confused, I am under the impression that LXC is a Linux kernel feature, so it should be present in Kernel itself. However, looking at the above site viz: `https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/introduction/`,  is this same when we say LXC (the kernel feature)? Or is LXC provided to the Linux kernel by `https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/introduction/`?

How can I understand this subtle difference?

Comment: `I am under the impression that LXC is a Linux kernel feature, so it should be present in Kernel` The first sentence in the link you linked says `LXC is a userspace interface` and then below it does `LXC uses the following kernel features`. It's not a "kernel feature" it's a "userspace interface".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if you can, could you pl elaborate a bit? From what I understood: Linux kernel provides --> Cgroups, namespaces (so they are pure Linux kernel features); and LXC (from linuxcontainers) use those features? Is this correct interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the core features needed to operate Linux in containers are built into the kernel -- namespaces, control groups, virtual roots, etc. However, to assemble a usable container platform from these features requires a considerable amount of infrastructure. We need to manage container storage, create network links between containers, control per-container resource usage, etc. User-space programs can, and are, used to provide this infrastructure, and the tooling that goes with it.

I have written a series of articles on building a container from scratch that explains some of these issues:

http://kevinboone.me/containerfromscratch.html

It's possible in principle to build and connect containers using nothing but the features built into the kernel, and a bunch of shell scripts. Tools like LXC, Docker, and Podman all use the same kernel features (so far as I know), but they manipulate these features in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. So, LXC is just a tool to create a container, which otherwise can be created by plain vanilla commands (albeit difficult to do).  Is it correct to say, "containers" a generic team (concept of Linux Kernel), and "Linux Container", the one created by "LXC".  If so, then what's the name given to the container created by Docker (it uses libContainer now)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know -- "container" seems to have become a somewhat overloaded term.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, very informative. I referred to the wiki, there also it is mentioned the same, LXC uses the core concepts of the Linux kernel to create a container. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC

Comment: See this: http://www.haifux.org/lectures/299/netLec7.pdf ; low level, provieded in wiki reference docs in above link.